# Why aren't there any competitors in the market for epi-pens?

Tags: injections

We've seen recently that the price of epi-pens has been jacked up six-fold due to one company having a monopoly on the market.

Medically this is quite important as anaphylaxis can kill in seconds.

My question is: **Why aren't there any competitors in the market for epi-pens?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Ludwig von Mises Institute (Economy Institute) has recently written an article about the lack of EpiPen Competitiors. It provides a good summary:

> EpiPen is sold by Mylan, and the price for a pack of two has increased
>   from about $100 in 2007 to over $600 as of May 2016. (...) With the
>   FDA, patents, and cozy insurance relationships, Mylan has been able to
>   steadily increase the price of EpiPens without significant market
>   repercussions.
>
> Epinephrine is extremely cheap—just a few cents per dose. **The
>   complications come from producing the easy auto-injecting devices.
>   Mylan “owns” their auto-injector device design, so competitors must
>   find work-arounds in their devices to deliver the epinephrine into the
>   patient’s body.**
>
> A French pharmaceutical company offered an electronic device that
>   actually talks people through the steps of administering the drug, but
>   it was recalled because of concerns about it delivering the required
>   dose. **Just this year, Teva Pharmaceutical’s attempt at bringing a
>   generic epinephrine injector to market in the US was blocked by the
>   FDA.** Adrenaclick and Twinject were unable to get insurance companies
>   on board and so discontinued their injectors in 2012.
>
> Adrenaclick has since come back, but it is still not covered by many
>   insurance plans, and the FDA has made it illegal for pharmacies to
>   substitute Adrenaclick as a generic alternative to EpiPen. Another
>   company tried to sidestep the whole auto-injector patent barrier by
>   offering prefilled syringes, but the FDA has stalled them, too.

https://mises.org/blog/lack-epipen-competitors-fdas-fault

Here another source in the NY Times which provides some insights too:

http://www.nytimes.com/2016/08/25/business/mylan-raised-epipens-price-before-the-expected-arrival-of-a-generic.html?_r=0

Comment: It's part regulatory, but I'd say that's more or less standard for a new product. The problem here is that the market is too small to justify large expenses to get past the FDA (because everything has to be tested & equivalence has to be proven). Competitors also run the risk that when they finally enter the market, Mylan will just return the price to $100, ruining all profit margins.